# Save() returning NULL, Not saving data

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I am trying to save data into the orders table. But the save method returns NULL. I have given the data also.

Here is code what I am trying to do.

```
$OrderData = [
    'order_name' => 56,
    'order_status_id' => '2',
    'order_date' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
    'order_address' => '',
    'order_suburb' => '',
    'order_state' => '',
    'order_postcode' => '',
    'order_country' => '',
    'client_id' => 55
];
$this->loadModel('Orders');
$orderData = $this->Orders->newEntity($OrderData, ['validate' => false]);
debug($this->Orders->save($orderData));die;
var_dump($this->Orders->save($orderData));die;
```

debug returns false.
var_dump returns bool(false).
I can't even check the SQL query generated by the cake ORM, as save method is not an object.
I am trying to do this from the Logins Controller.
$orderData is an entity with data, it's not null.

Comment: With `pr()` you cannot tell the difference between `null`, `false`, and `''`. Use `debug()`, for the result as well as the entity after invoking `save()`.

Comment: debug(), returns me false. What should I do now? BTW can you say me please the what is the cause by looking at the codes? @ndm

Comment: As suggested, debug the entity after invoking `save()`. If no errors are found in there, inspect the genereated SQL queries.

Comment: try to print the sql statement .and run that query in database .so that you will get what error the query may have and what are all data it contains.ref : <?php echo $this->element('sql_dump'); ?> or enable sql_dump. and also check if any field is null which should not be null in db and check for date format also

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In CakePHP `['validate' => false]`, will not validate your fields(fields which are needed While creating or updating) simple we can say `validationDefault()` validations will not validate but will validate the `buildRules()` rules(the exist in rules and Unique rules). So that I was getting an error because of my client_id had not existed in the Clients table.

I have debugged my code using the method `errors()`, like `$orderData->errors();`

Answer (score 1):

Try `debug($orderData->getErrors());` just to make sure there are no validation errors on the entity object.

OR

Use error() directly to the entity, like `pr($orderData->errors());die;`. However the `$entity->errors()` method is deprecated since 3.4.0 and should be replaced by `$entity->getErrors()`.

Comment: Please note this line $this->Orders->newEntity($OrderData, ['validate' => false]); in my reference code.

Comment: Yeah I saw the line :) However I remember I had a similar problem and found out, that a validation rule I had was processed by the save method, not the newEntity method. At least as far as I remember it. So I got used to always debug $entity->getErrors() in case a save method returns false.

Comment: There's validation rules (marshalling time) and application rules (saving time), the latter being able to utilize the former @bikash.bilz

Answer (score -1):

try this :

```
$OrderData = [
    'order_name' => 56,
    'order_status_id' => '2',
    'order_date' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
    'order_address' => '',
    'order_suburb' => '',
    'order_state' => '',
    'order_postcode' => '',
    'order_country' => '',
    'client_id' => 55
];
$this->loadModel('Orders');
$saveData = $this-> Orders->newEntity();
$saveData = $this-> Orders->patchEntity($saveData, $OrderData);
$saveData = $this-> Orders->save($saveData);
```

Comment: ok whats your problem? data has not save properly or something else.

Comment: Data is not saving and also my save method returning bool data not object.

Comment: share your code of Orders model &  screenshot of your table structure